# Search an array of lists for a specific string, then create boolean for all elements with smaller indices

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, extract, indices

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
a_few_lists=
array([['A', 'B', '-', 'C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'F', 'G', '-', 'H'],
       ['I', 'J', '-', 'K', 'L']], dtype='<U2')
```

I want to search each row for the '-' and create an array that marks those left of it as true. I also want to delete that element. I have gotten the indices for the string by using `np.nonzero(a_few_lists == '-')[1]` returning `[2,3,2]`. I could use these to remove the '-' fairly easily but I also want to mark the other elements.

Desired output:

```
array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
       ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']], dtype='<U2')

array([[True, True, False, False],
       [True, True, True, False],
       [True, True, False, False]])
```

Comment: "I also want to delete that element.". Is there any particular reason you are using `numpy`? Note, this won't work if there isn't the same number of `-` in every row

Comment: `a_few_lists` That's a multidimensional NumPy array though, no? I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, it would be good to get some more context for this.

Comment: Can there be multiple occurrences of '-' ?